# Newton-Raphson using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have written the following code to calculate square roots using Newton's method, but it overflows every time I run it. I have tried checking it myself but I didn't find any mistake. Can you guys help me out?

```
double root(double n,double init){
    if(fabs(init*init-n)<=0.00001){
        return init;
    }else{
        init=(init*init-n)/2*init;
        return root(n,init);
   }
}
int main()
{
    double a;
    cout<<"Enter any number to get its square root: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Square Root of "<<a<<" is: "<<root(a,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would try outputting the parameters sent to **root** so that I could see them, also the value calculated for **init** in the assignment statement. If you compare what you see with what you expect to get you will probably soon see what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your newton raphson method is correct? If you think so, do explain it slightly with comments.

Comment: gowrath i saw the formula and derived it myself too. formula seems to be ok. i think the problem is in implementation

Comment: @MuhammadDabeerUddinFarooqi  see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your issue is two-fold. Firstly, your Newton method is slightly off (which is a bigger issue). Secondly the way you are implementing it is leading to overflow.

## Issue 1 (bigger issue):

The other answers seem to ignore this even though this is the bigger issue. Computers can handle the overflow from squaring for small numbers like when calculating the square root of 9, but your method doesn't work even for them. This is because, as I mentioned in the comment, your Newton method is slightly off.

You should be using a plus instead of a minus in this line (try rederiving to see why):

```
init=(init*init+n)/(2*init);
```

Derivation:

```
x_{k+1} = x_k - f(x_k)/f'(x_k)
        = x_k - ((x_k)^2 - n)/(2x_k)
        = x_k - 1/2*x_k + n/(2x_k)  // note the + here
        = 0.5*x_k + 0.5*n/x_k
        = 0.5*(x_k + n/x_k)
```

where `x_k` is your `init` variable.

## Issue 2:

Doing `init*init` can cause the numbers to grow too quickly and overflow (there is more error in bigger numbers). You can algebraically rewrite this as:

```
init=0.5*(init + n/init);
```

Putting this together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double root(double n,double init){
    if(fabs(init*init-n)<=0.00001){
        return init;
    }else{
        init=0.5*(init + n/init);
        return root(n,init);
   }
}
int main()
{
    double a;
    cout<<"Enter any number to get its square root: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Square Root of "<<a<<" is: "<<root(a,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot i just changed that - to + and rewrote the formula as you guided and it worked. Thanks a lot. but can you guide me on that sign thingy(as the original - in eq)??

Comment: @MuhammadDabeerUddinFarooqi I added the derivation in the answer. Does that answer your question? If not don't hesitate to ask any clarifying questions!

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion, which may overflow your stack. For example, I tried to input 9999 and your program hangs like for ever (because n is not reduced).

The other problem is double*double may overflow.

The correct (efficient, concise and iterative) version is:

```
double root(double n){ // you dont need the second parameter
    double val = n; // initial guess
    for(;;) {
        double last = val;
        val = (val + n / val) * 0.5; // iterative
        if (abs(val - last) < 1e-9) break;  // error small enough
    }
    return val;
}
```

and if you insist on recursion, here is a more concise recursion implementation:

```
double root(double n, double last){
    if (abs(last * last - n) < 1e-9) { // good guess
            return last;
    }
    return root(n, 0.5 * (last + n / last)); // recursive call
}
```

Also [see "Newton Iterative Sqrt Method"](https://helloacm.com/newton-iterative-sqrt-method/) for more information.

Comment: You subtly changed his newton method, not just algebraically rearranged it.

Comment: I know.. I don't recommend using recursion and clearly iterative is the standard implementation of newton although they both implement the same idea.

Comment: No I mean, the recursion is not the issue here (although I agree iterative is better). His newton method rearranges to `val = (val - n/val)*0.5` instead of `val = (val + n/val)*0.5` as you have in your answer. The former does not converge as readily and also is not going to calculate the square root. See my answer for an explanation. Nevertheless, I completely agree with the suggestion to do this iteratively instead :)

Comment: OK.. I tried a few inputs and it confirms that his initial approach does not converge (which causes recursion to overflow the stack)

Comment: Actually question asks to do it using recursion. So please could you write using recursive approach?

Comment: @MuhammadDabeerUddinFarooqi   Added!

Comment: nobody thought my answer is useful?  losing interest in this site... :(